# It's correct to have 2 constructors, one for Dependency Injection and the other one Resolving the injection?

Tags: c#, constructor, code-injection

I have 2 constructor in my class:

```
public class CacheWebServices : ICacheWebService
    {
        public ICache apiConnector { get; set; }

        public CacheWebServices(ICache ApiConnector)
        {
            apiConnector = ApiConnector;
        }

        public CacheWebServices()
            : this(new VuelingCache())
        { }
    }
```

As you can see, I have one constructor  depending on IVuelingCache and a default constructor that creates an instance to pass to the first constructor. Is it correct? in this way i get rid of the Factory class.

Comment: How are you expecting to *use* these constructors? When would you want to tightly couple the web service to the implementation (which is what the second one does)?

Comment: What tool are you using for Dependency Injection?

Answer (score 5):

This is one way to ensure that you have a valid instance of `IVuelingCache` - this pattern has a name - poor man's dependency injection.

[Some](http://lostechies.com/chadmyers/2009/07/14/just-say-no-to-poor-man-s-dependency-injection/) [see](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/07/03/how-not-to-do-dependency-injection-in-nerddinner/) [this](http://blog.jonathanoliver.com/2009/07/poor-man%E2%80%99s-dependency-injection-take-42-action/) as an anti-pattern, as you are hard coding the "default" implementation into your code.

Comment: I know I'm coupling my code and making a "new" in my constructor. But it's very easy to use, it does not need a factory to resolve te dependencies, and it's not gonna change the implementation so, I preffer the ease of use instead of the purity of Dependency Injection.

Comment: If DI is used for testing only, it's acceptable- see http://devlicio.us/blogs/tim_barcz/archive/2009/07/12/why-there-s-nothing-wrong-with-dependency-injection-in-nerddinner.aspx

Answer (score 2):

There is some debate as to that pattern being a good idea:

http://lostechies.com/chadmyers/2009/07/14/just-say-no-to-poor-man-s-dependency-injection/

In my opinion, if you have *a good default* that isn't a logically external dependency, then you should provide that default.  If your "default" really shouldn't be a default, or would couple pieces that are too far from each other too strongly, then do not use that pattern.

You couple your code by doing this, so really think long and hard about whether it will be used as a convenience default for locally available default implementations, or if you're really just using this as a crutch, and causing inappropriately strong coupled dependencies.

Also, many people advocate using constructor injection only for *required* dependencies, and using property injection for *optional* dependencies.  When you use the poor-man's DI pattern, you are making an optional (or defaultable) dependency.  You might want to consider using property injection for these optional-dependency cases, as that is the pattern many people expect.

Comment: If you have good default, property injection might be a better pattern.

Comment: @Steven: Fully agree with that sentiment.  Will add it.

Comment: If you have _optional_ dependencies it's probably a sign that you should split your class, because it's doing too much work.

Comment: @0lukasz0: I call them optional because that's what I remember seeing them labeled.  It is a default, really.  Classes that use certain logging patterns often use them for a default "null" logger, for example.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few problems with your approach:

1. It makes your code less understandable. Not only is it more code to write, but it is harder to see what dependencies the class takes. When you have one single constructor, it is immediately clear what its dependencies are.
2. It makes the class depend on concrete instances. This makes it hard to separate abstraction and implementation and could be bad from an architectural point of view.
3. It forces you to make changes to that class when implementations change, which is bad for maintainability. Say for instance your application uses `ICommandHandler<T>` interfaces as abstraction to execute business commands and that your class depends on an `ICommandHandler<UpdateUserCommand>` and points at the concrete `UpdateUserCommandHandler`. When you later on want to wrap any `ICommandHandler<T>` inside a `DurationLoggingCommandHandler<T>`, `DeadLockRetryCommandHandler<T>` or  what not, you need to go through your complete application to replace all dependencies, while otherwise it is just a matter of rewiring the configuration in the startup path of your application.

For more information on the downside of having multiple constructors, see [this article](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/posts/2013/di-anti-pattern-multiple-constructors/).

Answer (score 1):

No this is not a good Idea, because your class woul become knowledge about the implementation of `IVuelingCache` ( `new VuelingCache()` ).