# PHP Dependency Injection Management

Tags: php, oop, dependency-injection

I have Created a PHP package where I applied [solid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) principles, which was great, however I ended up having many separate dependencies to be injected in the main class or module which will be then used.

**example :**

```
$dataViewer   = new DataViewer;
$dataProvider = new DataProvider;
$dataParser   = new DataParser;
$dataSaver    = new DataSaver;
```

... and then use all these dependencies in my main module or class like so:

```
$myPackage = new MyPackage($dataViewer, $dataProvider, $dataParser, $dataSaver);
```

Then I use my package.

Is there a way to make this a little bit easier for those who use this package and need only to get an instance of MyPackage instead of injecting all these dependencies.

Comment: You would need to create your own configuration and auto-wiring system. See how Symfony does it, for example. As it is, this question is not bad but is **too broad** for Stack Overflow's requirements.

Comment: Read [this](https://blog.trikoder.net/autowiring-on-the-inside-or-how-to-make-your-own-in-php-4570b762c24c), for example.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24407778) comment could help you. Remember that there are a lot of ways to inject dependencies, maybe by setters/getters?